# Set the number of buffer option in 'initdb' command in MacOS? 'PostgreSQL'

Tags: postgresql

For a Homework reason I need to initialize a PostgreSQL database with limited number of buffer to do some debug & testing, etc.

I recalled that in Linux you can do:

```
~/bin/initdb -B 100 -D ~/dir/data
```

or

```
~/bin/postgres -B 100 -D ~/dir/data
```

to start up the server or init the db with 100 buffers, but in my MacOS it shows

```
initdb: invalid option -- B
```

I am using PostgreSQL 10.5, did they changed it in MacOS or just me having the wrong cmd for Mac?

Comment: `initdb` has [no such option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html) - what kind of "buffer" are you trying to set there? If you want to set [shared_buffers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS) you will need to edit `postgresql.conf` afterwards or pass the value when starting Postgres

Comment: You should not rely on memory.  That is why we have documentation.  "initdb" does not have a `-B` option.  But "postgres" does.  You indicate that you tried that.  What error did you get?